# Set the vertical space between the lines of code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working in jupyter notebook, with python code.

I want to increase the vertical space between the lines of code. For example,  I have this code:

```
a=2 
b=3
```

I want to change it to:

```
a=2 

b=3
```

Do you know any trick to set this space? Thanks

I am trying to use the setting from edit part. But it can not work.

Comment: Hit Enter one extra time.

Comment: @pavel. Thanks. I thought that maybe there is a line that set it automatically. I dont need exactly one extra enter.